# How to print a star instead of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numbers

I need to write a function numbers_around(n, k) that prints the numbers smaller and larger than n in order. Instead of the number n, it should print an asterisk.

***What I've done:***

```
def numbers_around(n, k):
    for n in range((n-k),(n+k+1)):
        print(n, end=' ')
    print()

numbers_around(15, 3)        
numbers_around(8, 6)        
numbers_around(27, 2)
```

***My output:***

```
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
25 26 27 28 29
```

***The output needed:***

```
12 13 14 * 16 17 18 
2 3 4 5 6 7 * 9 10 11 12 13 14 
25 26 * 28 29
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same name for two variables, this is bad practice. If you change one of the variable in the for loop and check if it is equal to the original number you can print out a "*" when needed like so:

```
def numbers_around(n, k):
    for i in range((n-k),(n+k+1)):
        if i == n:
            print("*", end = " ")
        else:
            print(i, end=' ')
    print()

numbers_around(15, 3)        
numbers_around(8, 6)        
numbers_around(27, 2)
```